# Where do I get the mdefs.h file?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, code-generation

I want to generate some C code, and the reference [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneratingCAndFortranExpressions.html) says that Mathematica comes with a `mdefs.h` file, but I cannot find it. Is there a place where I can download it?

Comment: In my version of Mathematica, mdefs.h is residing in the directory `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C/`

Comment: Found it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, the answer is `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C/`. Thanks Heike!